# Android MapView Pointer blink Effect

Tags: android, android-mapview, effect, blink

i have created a map view and i want to show the blink effect on pointer like it have on google maps on Android Devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following tutorial : http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=148

You have to add the MyLocationOverlay to the MapView.

Comment: I have added location overlay but i want my marker to blink like it does on android phones

Comment: For me it is blinking. The icon is not the same as in Google Maps but it is blinking. Google Maps has a blinking arrow ... I have a blinking dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to this link and download the files,It sample app with blinking dot on map.
and help to drag and drop the dot.
Tap on Droped Pin will display a Baloon with location Info.

any difficulty connect me on binilthomaspr@gmail.com

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8lwwsnmi3s0r5lv/rGIbR2ski4